# How do I edit a subplot axis on a Facet plot in altair?

Tags: altair

After I use a facet to generate several subplots on my data, how can I edit the y-axis label on one of the subplots? I tend to need to do this because I plot multiple metrics, and some of them are %'s, which I want to format differently.

To be more specific, with the example code below, how would I change the y-axis label of the middle subplot from 'petalWidth' to 'custom'?

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
iris = data.iris()

alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalLength:Q',
    y='petalWidth:Q',
    color='species:N'
).properties(
    width=180,
    height=180
).facet(
    facet='species:N',
    columns=3
).resolve_scale(
    y='independent',
)
```

Comment: If you are interesting in plotting multiple different metrics, it sounds like `repeat` would be more suitable than `facet`, since it can plot multiple columns from your dataframe rather than subgroups of the same column as for `facet`. Using `repeat` and naming the colunmns in the dataframe the same as your want the axis titles to be named is probably the easiest solution. For more control, you can use `concat` with loops

Comment: If I `concat` with loops, the shared axis I end up with will have repeated, redundant axis labels. The only way I've been able to get rid of repeated, redundant axis labels is to use `facet`. Unfortunately, I cede control of things like `format`, as in the original question.

Comment: You can control the axis labels when you loop and only place them on the desired axis (but I agree this is additional work over being able to control it on the faceted axis after the fact).